# Find out the path on which file is saved

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am saving a file using

```
d.execCommand( 'SaveAs', false , name )
```

Can I know the path at which file is getting saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm almost certain you can't. All you can control is the filename suggested by the save dialog.

Comment: so is there an alternative to this command i do want save as dialog box to appear..

Comment: I don't know of any other way of programmatically causing a save dialog to appear. Why do you need the file path on the user's hard drive anyway?

Comment: But you're already specifying the (suggested) file name with your `name` variable in the last parameter passed to `execCommand`. You won't be able to get any information back after you've made the save dialog appear, apart from whether the user saved the page or not (returned as a Boolean by the `execCommand()` call).

Comment: This is a security feature and by design that you cannot get knowledge of the remote user's drive.  If you have a legit reason for needing this, you can consider writing your own ActiveX control.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Indeed, and I should have mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: @jeff & Tim - actually i need to write a file locally on client side using javascript, and get it save it with "UTF-8" unicode... it is getting saved as Normal unicode which is not serving my purpose...
please refer the code [snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384635/how-to-set-encoding-to-utf-8-in-following-code-snipped)
Any help??