# How to return the filename and path from execCommand() in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function save_content_to_file(content, filename){
    var dlg = false;
    with(document){
        ir=createElement('iframe');
        ir.id='ifr';
        ir.location='about.blank';
        ir.style.display='none';
        body.appendChild(ir);
        with(getElementById('ifr').contentWindow.document){
            open("text/plain", "replace");
            charset = "utf-8";
            write(content);
            close();
            document.charset = "utf-8";
            dlg = execCommand('SaveAs', false, filename+'.txt');
        }
        body.removeChild(ir);
    }
    return dlg;
}
```

I am calling the above code by invoking the function save_content_to_file("hello world","C:\A.txt"). When the above code gets executed, a SaveAs dailog box gets opened. The user can traverse to any directory and save the file with any name. My question is how to get the directory path and filename that user has specified while saving the file. The filename variable just contains "C:\A.txt". I want to return the complete path and filename that is specified by the user.

Thanks in advance. Yukti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the path on which file is saved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386144/find-out-the-path-on-which-file-is-saved)